# Watermelondb with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, watermelondb

I am building a React App and I wish to use Watermelondb for Offline Storage, but I don`t know how to use it with TypeScript. I have created the database and my Course and Lesson model files from Watermelondb library. In my App.tsx I have used the Database provider as follows:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React from 'react';
import { View, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import DatabaseProvider from '@nozbe/watermelondb/DatabaseProvider';

import database from './database/index.js';

import AppProvider from './hooks';

import Routes from './routes';

const App: React.FC = () => (
  <NavigationContainer>
    <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" backgroundColor="#6548A3" translucent />
    <DatabaseProvider database={database}>
      <AppProvider>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#6548A3' }}>
        <Routes />
      </View>
    </AppProvider>
    </DatabaseProvider>
  </NavigationContainer>
);

export default App;
```

Then I get a Typescript error in my functional component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
const Dashboard: React.FC = ({courses, lessons}) => {
return (
    <View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

In courses and lessons I get the following error:

> Property does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'

How can I use TypeScript to solve these errors?

Answer (score 0):

`React.FC` is a generic which depends on props.  The keys `courses` and `lessons` must exist on your props type in order to destructure them.  When don't set a generic and just use `React.FC` that means that the component does not take any props.

You want something like:

```
interface DashboardProps {
  courses: Course[]; // an array of some Course type that you need to define
  lessons: Lesson[]; // same for lessons
}

const Dashboard: React.FC<DashboardProps> = ({courses, lessons}) => {
return (
    <View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: But courses and lessons come from DatabseProvider and they have a defined type on watermelondb. I want to know the type used by watermelondb. Courses and lessons represent the table in databse, so I need to specify the type for these tables.